# Cumulative Frequency Histogram

Tags: r

I want my Cumulative Relative Frequency Graph looks like has a histogram inside. For my code, see below:

```
max.data=max(week_final2$cured)
min.data=min(week_final2$cured)

slice=round((max.data-min.data)/25)
breaks=seq(min.data, max.data, by=slice)

cut.data=cut(week_final2$cured, breaks, right=FALSE)
cut.data

frequency=table(cut.data)
frequency

cummul.freq=cumsum(frequency)
cummul.freq

relative.frequency=frequency/sum(frequency)

cf=as.data.frame(cummul.freq)
cf
cummul.freq=cf[,1]
cummul.freq

cummul.percentile=cummul.freq/max(cummul.freq)
Cured_Freq <- cbind(frequency,relative.frequency,cummul.freq, cummul.percentile)

graph.cummul.perc =c(0, cummul.percentile)

plot(breaks, graph.cummul.perc, ylab="Relative Cumulative Frequency", 
     main="Weeks that Children are Cured(CURED)")
lines(breaks, graph.cummul.perc)
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal & reproducible example including sample data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). It's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve. Posting code without sample data makes it difficult for others to reproduce your code attempt and understand your goal.

Answer (score 0):

The default histogram function has some of the information you're looking for. If you store it without plotting, you can do something like this:

```r
x <- rnorm(1000)
breaks <- 30

distPlot <- function(x,breaks=25){
  require(ggplot2)
  require(dplyr)

  h <- hist(x,breaks = breaks,freq = F,plot = F)

  as_tibble(h[c('mids','density')]) %>%
    mutate(cdist=cumsum(density),rfreq=density/max(density)) %>% 
    mutate(cdist = cdist/max(cdist))%>%
    ggplot()+
    geom_col(aes(x=mids,y=rfreq))+
    geom_line(aes(x=mids,y=cdist))+
    xlab('x')+
    ylab('Relative frequency')
}

distPlot(x=x,breaks = breaks)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
#> Loading required package: dplyr
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
#> Warning in hist.default(x, breaks = breaks, freq = F, plot = F): argument
#> 'freq' is not made use of
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-08-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>